# Testing eventEmitter which has an async function listener using jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, google-cloud-pubsub, eventemitter

I defined an `async` function which has `await` statements in it and using this as a listener to on message of pubsub subscription. Would like to test this using jest. But facing a problem with it.

code:

```
const pubsubPull = () => {
  const pubsub = new PubSub();
  const subscription = pubsub.subscription("test-sub");
  const handler = async message => {
    try {
      const payload = Buffer.from(message.data, "base64").toString();
      const data = JSON.parse(payload).data;
      await repository.insert(data);
      message.ack();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error")
    }
  };
  subscription.on("message", handler);
};
```

test:

```
jest.mock("@google-cloud/pubsub");
jest.mock("./repository");

describe("listener", () => {
  const data = {
    id: "3ce91594-f648-41bf-9a37-4fa09c4afb3b",
    name: "ABCD",
    value: 1234
  };
  const eventBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data));
  const message = {
    id: "1561624788277",
    data: eventBuffer,
    ack: jest.fn()
  };

  const mockSubscripton = new EventEmitter();
  const pubsubClient = {
    subscription: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockSubscripton)
  };

  beforeAll(() => {
    PubSub.mockImplementation(() => pubsubClient);
    repository.insert.mockResolvedValue(true);
  });

  it("should ack the message", (done) => {
    pubsubPull();
    mockSubscripton.emit("message", message);

    expect(message.ack).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
  });
});
```

Test is failing with 
`Expected mock function to have been called.
But it was not called.`
That means assertion is done even before the completion of listener function execution. 
How can I wait for it to be done and run the assertion.
Any help appreciated.
node v10.11.0, jest "24.8.0"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A naive but simple solution would be to use a `setTimeout` to make your assertions, giving your async subscriber enough time to execute.

```
it("should ack the message", done => {
  pubsubPull();
  mockSubscripton.emit("message", message);

  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(message.ack).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: yes, did this as a workaround. but just asking if we can have a better solution to achieve it. thanks @nehero

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new waitable mock function and wait for it

```js
function jestFnWaitable() {
  let resolve
  const promise = new Promise((_resolve) => (resolve = _resolve))
  const mock = jest.fn(() => {
    resolve()
  })
  mock.promise = promise
  return mock
}

const message = {
  ...,
  ack: jestFnWaitable()
}

it("should ack the message", (done) => {
  pubsubPull();
  mockSubscripton.emit("message", message);
  await message.ack.promise;
  expect(message.ack).toHaveBeenCalled();
  done();
});
```

Adjusted from: https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/7432