# Jest can't test an awaited promise, it times out instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, axios, jestjs

I switched from just running an axios GET, to returning a promise, and now my Jest test is failing:

Downloading the zip in 'resource.js':

```js
async function downloadMtgJsonZip() {
  const path = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', fileName);
  const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(path);

  console.info('...connecting...');
  const { data, headers } = await axios({
    url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'stream',
  });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let error = null;
    const totalLength = headers['content-length'];
    const progressBar = getProgressBar(totalLength);
    console.info('...starting download...');
    data.on('data', (chunk) => progressBar.tick(chunk.length));
    data.pipe(writer);
    writer.on('error', (err) => {
      error = err;
      writer.close();
      reject(err);
    });
    writer.on('close', () => {
      const now = new Date();
      console.info(`Completed in ${(now.getTime() - progressBar.start) / 1000} seconds`);
      if (!error) resolve(true);
      // no need to call the reject here, as it will have been called in the
      // 'error' stream;
    });
  });
}
```

Neither of the following tests in 'resource.spec.js' pass now:

```js
it('fetches successfully data from an URL', async () => {
    const onFn = jest.fn();
    const data = { status: 200, data: { pipe: () => 'data', on: onFn }, headers: { 'content-length': 100 } };

    const writerOnFn = jest.fn();

    axios.mockImplementationOnce(() => data);
    fs.createWriteStream.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ on: writerOnFn }));
    await downloadMtgJsonZip();
    expect(onFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith('data', expect.any(Function));
    expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({ url: 'https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/AllPrintings.json.zip' }),
    );
    expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({ responseType: 'stream' }),
    );
  });
  it('ticks up the progress bar', async () => {
    const tickFn = jest.fn();
    const dataOnFn = jest.fn((name, func) => func(['chunk']));
    const data = { status: 200, data: { pipe: () => 'data', on: dataOnFn }, headers: { 'content-length': 1 } };

    const writerOnFn = jest.fn();

    ProgressBar.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ tick: tickFn }));
    axios.mockImplementationOnce(() => data);
    fs.createWriteStream.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ on: writerOnFn }));
    await downloadMtgJsonZip();

    expect(ProgressBar).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.stringContaining('downloading'),
      expect.objectContaining({
        total: 1,
      }),
    );
    expect(tickFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
  });
});
```

Of note, VSCode is telling me that for `axios` in 'resource.js' 'this expression is not callable' and that *nothing* has `mockImplementationOnce` (it 'does not exist on type...').

Previously my `downloadMtgJsonZip` looked like this:

```js
async function downloadMtgJsonZip() {
  const path = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', 'AllPrintings.json.zip');
  const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(path);

  console.info('...connecting...');
  const { data, headers } = await axios({
    url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'stream',
  });
  const totalLength = headers['content-length'];
  const progressBar = getProgressBar(totalLength);
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (progressBar.complete) {
      const now = new Date();
      console.info(`Completed in ${(now.getTime() - progressBar.start) / 1000} seconds`);
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 100);
  console.info('...starting download...');
  data.on('data', (chunk) => progressBar.tick(chunk.length));
  data.pipe(writer);
}
```

and the only line that is different in the test is the mock for createWriteStream was simpler (it read `fs.createWriteStream.mockImplementationOnce(() => 'fs');`)

I've tried adding:

```js
  afterEach(() => { 
    jest.clearAllMocks(); 
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
```

I've tried adding in `writerOnFn('close');` to try and get the `writer.on('close', ...)` to trigger.

But I am till getting this error:

> : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

I can't figure out what is missing, to make the async call to be 'invoked'. The [last time I had this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63190075/1075247) mocking out `createWriteStream` fixed my issue, but I don't see anything else to mock out?

How do I get these tests to pass again?

Comment: Do they work if you increase the test timeout using `jest.setTimeout(30000)` ?

Comment: @Mackan90096 I will try that when I get access to the code at home. Is there part of my code or test code that would exceed the default time out?

Comment: From what I can read, the only part that would exceed the timeout be if the file you're reading is very large.

Comment: @Mackan90096 both the `axios` call and the `createWriteStream` are mocked out though? They shouldn't touch any real files

Comment: My bad, I misread the code. The only thing I can think of right now is that the mocked `fs.createWriteStream` doesn't have its `on` function called, which you were looking at.

The (best) solution to test EventEmitters like `fs.createWriteStream` is to use a [callback in jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks)

Comment: @Mackan90096 brilliant, I'll look at that as soon as I can

Comment: @mackan90096 I had a look and a play around but nothing seemed to work, will keep trying though

Comment: @Mackan90096 I can see I was doing *one* of already, but I don't think the `callback` option is the best for me. I tried to return the promise, and put the expect in `then`, and I tried to put it all in timeout like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57594842/1075247)... nothing. Now I'm looking at this [dev.to](https://dev.to/shelob9/testing-event-emitter-38b5) guide. Wish me luck.

Comment: @Mackan90096 did you get to take another look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do the event handlers attached using `writer.on(event, handler)` get invoked in the test code? Wouldn't the `writerOnFn` mock need to call the handler function being passed in? If those aren't being invoked, then `resolve(true)` is never being called and so the call to `await downloadMtgJsonZip();` inside the test never resolves.

I would think you'd need something like this

```
const writerOnFn = jest.fn((e, cb) => if (e === 'close') cb())
```

Of course, you may want to flesh it out to differentiate between the 'error' and 'close' events, or just make sure to alter it if you have tests around the 'error' condition.

Comment: This looks promising! I have tried to call just `writerOnFn('close')` since posting the question, but I've not thought to do what you wrote here. I will try as soon as I can ( it now, hopefully in the morning)

Comment: That's Worked! Amazing

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score -1):

Jest has a default timeout of 5000ms for async tests to complete (ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testtimeout-number)

If you have long running async calls it becomes necessary to increase this threshold.

For example in my `jest.config.js` the timeout is set to 60000ms

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  testTimeout: 60000, 
}
```

Comment: My async calls should all be mocked out and take no time at all though, unless you can spot one in my code that isn't mocked out?

Comment: I've tried this and it did not work