# Emitting an error in my jest test doesn't trigger the error handler as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, event-handling

My download code relies on listening on listening for events to determine when to fire callbacks, and whether the promise it's in should be resolved or rejected:

```js
async function downloadMtgJsonZip() {
  const path = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', fileName);
  const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(path);

  console.info('...connecting...');
  const { data, headers } = await axios({
    url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'stream',
  });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timeout = 20000;
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timed out'); // debug log
      writer.close();
      reject(new Error(`Promise timed out after ${timeout} ms`));
    }, timeout);
    let error = null;
    const totalLength = headers['content-length'];
    const progressBar = getProgressBar(totalLength);
    console.info('...starting download...');
    // set up data and writer listeners
    data.on('data', (chunk) => progressBar.tick(chunk.length));
    data.on('error', (err) => { // added this to see if it would be triggered - it is not
      console.log(`did a data error: ${error}`);
      error = err;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      writer.close();
      reject(err);
    });
    writer.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log(`did a writer error: ${error}`);
      error = err;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      writer.close();
      reject(err);
    });
    writer.on('close', () => {
      const now = new Date();
      console.log(`close called: ${now}`);
      console.log(`error is: ${error}`);
      console.info(
        `Completed in ${(now.getTime() - progressBar.start) / 1000} seconds`,
      );
      clearTimeout(timer);
      console.log(`time cleared: ${timer}`);
      if (!error) resolve(true);
      // no need to call the reject here, as it will have been called in the
      // 'error' stream;
    });
    // finally call data.pipe with our writer
    data.pipe(writer);
  });
}
```

I had some issues writing my tests, but I managed to get something that worked, despite feeling slightly messy, based on [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69458732/1075247):

Here is my test, with the relevant bits of my set up:

```js
describe('fetchData', () => {
  let dataChunkFn;
  let dataErrorFn;
  let dataOnFn;
  let writerCloseFn;
  let writerErrorFn;
  let writerOnFn;
  let pipeHandler;
  beforeEach(() => {
    // I've left all the mocking in place,
    // to give an idea of what I've set up
    const mockWriterEventHandlers = {};
    const mockDataEventHandlers = {};

    dataChunkFn = jest.fn((chunk) => mockDataEventHandlers.data(chunk));
    dataErrorFn = jest.fn((chunk) => mockDataEventHandlers.data(chunk));
    dataOnFn = jest.fn((e, cb) => {
      mockDataEventHandlers[e] = cb;
    });

    writerCloseFn = jest.fn(() => mockWriterEventHandlers.close());
    writerErrorFn = jest.fn(() => mockWriterEventHandlers.error());
    writerOnFn = jest.fn((e, cb) => {
      mockWriterEventHandlers[e] = cb;
    });
    const getMockData = (pipe) => ({
      status: 200,
      data: {
        pipe,
        on: dataOnFn,
      },
      headers: { 'content-length': 100 },
    });

    axios.mockImplementationOnce(() => getMockData(pipeHandler));
    fs.createWriteStream.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
      on: writerOnFn,
      close: writerCloseFn,
    }));
    jest.spyOn(console, 'info').mockImplementation(() => {});
    jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => {});
  });
  it.only('handles errors from the writer', async (done) => {
    console.log('writer error');
    expect.assertions(1);
    pipeHandler = (writer) => writer.emit('error', new Error('bang'));
    try {
      await downloadMtgJsonZip();
      done.fail('ran without error');
    } catch (exception) {
      // expect(dataErrorFn).toHaveBeenCalled(); // neither of these are called
      expect(writerErrorFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }
  });
```

I would have expected, that when `data(pipe)` ran, and the writer emitted a new error, it would have triggered at least one of the error listeners.

The code runs as expected, and it even handles the timeout (which I initially set too low), but this last test doesn't run.

As I commented above, neither of the functions above are called, so the `expect.assertions(1);` code fails the test.

It's possible I need to fundamentally change how I've written the tests, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Why doesn't that last test pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the code invokes `data.pipe(writer)`, it's running your `pipeHandler` function defined in the test. This function takes a given `writer` object and calls `writer.emit(...)`. I believe the issue is that the `writer` object being passed in is the one mocked out for `fs.createWriteStream()`, which doesn't have an `emit` method defined, so nothing is happening in response to that call. It is likely throwing an error, which you may be able to see in your catch block.

I believe what you want is to invoke the handlers saved by the `writerOnFn`. One way to do so would be to add a property to the object returned by your mock of `fs.createWriteStream` named `emit` and define it as a function that invokes the appropriate handler from inside `mockWriterEventHandlers`. I haven't tested this code but it would look something like the following

```
const writerEmitFn = (event, arg) => {
  mockWriterEventHandlers[event](arg);
}

fs.createWriteStream.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
  on: writerOnFn,
  close: writerCloseFn,
  emit: writerEmitFn,
}));
```

Comment: That is... Genius...! I'll try it in the morning insha'Allah

Comment: This works, however my tests don't for their own reason.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that `jest` is gobbling up the error.

In order to continue running in the case of exceptions, `jest` could be guarding against ever having to run `try` and `throw`.

You could try [expecting an error to have been thrown](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/781) using jest's API.

Comment: I need to make sure that writer.close is run though, is that still possible with your suggestion?

Comment: Assuming this `fs.createWriteStream.mockImplementationOnce` returns an object that has a method to `trigger` events. I'd be looking for a way to run `writer.trigger('close')`